# Cycle through links on page and open a link

Tags: macos, mac, firefox, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there a Firefox shortcut and/or combination of shortcuts to cycle through links on a page, then open a specific link ?

To do this now I use the shortcut : `'` to open find then I search for the link of interest then press 'Esc' to close find followed by 'Enter' key to open the link I'm interested in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Is there a Firefox shortcut to cycle through links on a page, then open a specific link?

On Windows and Linux:

> <kbd>Tab</kbd>/<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>    Jump to next/previous
>   link
>
> <kbd>Enter</kbd>  Open selected link in current tab

It doesn't seem to be possible on MacOS.

Source [Shortcut Pages for Firefox](https://shortcutworld.com/Firefox/Index)

Comment: Actually, on macOS Firefox 66.0.3 it works the same. I recall that working on many previous versions as well.